# Deserializing cXML to C# Class

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, cxml-commercexml

I'm trying to deserialize a cXML string into C# classes. However, when deserializing, I can't seem to get anything other than the root element to deserialize. [How to Deserialize XML document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document) seemed to provide the most help, and using that example I've managed to deserialize the root cXML tag, but this doesn't work on the nested object `PunchOutSetupRequest` which is the object I really need deserialized.

My question, before showing you the wall of code, is how can I properly deserialize these objects to the cXML classes defined below without changing the `cXML.cs` file? Since this is a standard I'd prefer not to edit it unless I absolutely have to. My code is fair game. Thank you in advance for any help since I know this topic is covered far and wide across SO.

I have this XSD file for cXML that I've used the `xsd.exe` tool to convert into C# classes. I won't paste the whole schema here to avoid diluting the question, but you can go to [cxml.org](http://www.cxml.org/) if you need a more complete picture.

**My Code for the cXML** which just deserializes the attributes and doesn't contain Header or Request objects defined in the cXML:

```
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(text))
            {
                try
                {
                    XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
                    xRoot.ElementName = "cXML";
                    xRoot.IsNullable = true;
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(cXML), xRoot);
                    cxml = (cXML)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string r = "";
                }
            }
```

**My code for the `PunchOutSetupRequest` deserialization.** This one throws an error when it sees cXML as the root node despite me setting the `xRoot` element to `PunchOutSetupRequest`.

```
using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(text))
            {
                try
                {
                    XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
                    xRoot.ElementName = "PunchOutSetupRequest";
                    xRoot.IsNullable = true;
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PunchOutSetupRequest), xRoot);
                    PunchOutSetupRequest request;
                    request = (PunchOutSetupRequest)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string r = "";
                }
            }
```

**text variable value (data redacted):**

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.1.007/cXML.dtd">
<cXML version="1.1.007" xml:lang="en-US" payloadID="" timestamp="2016-01-    04T03:21:32-05:00">
   <Header>
      <From>
         <Credential domain="">
            <Identity></Identity>
         </Credential>
      </From>
      <To>
         <Credential domain="">
            <Identity></Identity>
         </Credential>
      </To>
      <Sender>
         <Credential domain="">
            <Identity></Identity>
            <SharedSecret></SharedSecret>
         </Credential>
         <UserAgent></UserAgent>
      </Sender>
   </Header>
   <Request>
      <PunchOutSetupRequest operation="create">
         <BuyerCookie></BuyerCookie>
         <Extrinsic name="User"></Extrinsic>
         <BrowserFormPost>
            <URL></URL>
         </BrowserFormPost>
         <Contact>
            <Name xml:lang="en-US"></Name>
            <Email></Email>
         </Contact>
         <SupplierSetup>
            <URL></URL>
         </SupplierSetup>
      </PunchOutSetupRequest>
   </Request>
</cXML>
```

**cXML Class Generated by `xsd.exe` (fragmented)**

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/cXML")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/cXML", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class cXML
{

private object[] itemsField;

private string versionField;

private string payloadIDField;

private string timestampField;

private string langField;

public cXML()
{
    this.versionField = "1.1.010";
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Header", typeof(Header))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Message", typeof(Message))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Request", typeof(Request))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Response", typeof(Response))]
public object[] Items
{
    get
    {
        return this.itemsField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.itemsField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute("1.1.010")]
public string version
{
    get
    {
        return this.versionField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.versionField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public string payloadID
{
    get
    {
        return this.payloadIDField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.payloadIDField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public string timestamp
{
    get
    {
        return this.timestampField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.timestampField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")]
public string lang
{
    get
    {
        return this.langField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.langField = value;
    }
}
}    

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/cXML")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/cXML", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class PunchOutSetupRequest
{

private BuyerCookie buyerCookieField;

private Extrinsic[] extrinsicField;

private BrowserFormPost browserFormPostField;

private Contact[] contactField;

private SupplierSetup supplierSetupField;

private ShipTo shipToField;

private SelectedItem selectedItemField;

private ItemOut[] itemOutField;

private PunchOutSetupRequestOperation operationField;

/// <remarks/>
public BuyerCookie BuyerCookie
{
    get
    {
        return this.buyerCookieField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.buyerCookieField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Extrinsic")]
public Extrinsic[] Extrinsic
{
    get
    {
        return this.extrinsicField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.extrinsicField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
public BrowserFormPost BrowserFormPost
{
    get
    {
        return this.browserFormPostField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.browserFormPostField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Contact")]
public Contact[] Contact
{
    get
    {
        return this.contactField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.contactField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
public SupplierSetup SupplierSetup
{
    get
    {
        return this.supplierSetupField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.supplierSetupField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
public ShipTo ShipTo
{
    get
    {
        return this.shipToField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.shipToField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
public SelectedItem SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return this.selectedItemField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.selectedItemField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemOut")]
public ItemOut[] ItemOut
{
    get
    {
        return this.itemOutField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.itemOutField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public PunchOutSetupRequestOperation operation
{
    get
    {
        return this.operationField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.operationField = value;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Since it has been 6 weeks, do you still need an answer, or did you solve it already?

Comment: I did sort of. I did take a different approach by editing the cXML file. I believe the C# Classes generated by the xsd.exe tool were incorrect. The cXML I was receiving didn't seem to match the structure of the classes. Gutting what the xsd.exe tool provided seems to be working, though its a longer process.

Comment: Check the version of the CXML you're getting from your marketplace (or whatever).  The version you posted above is -really- old.  Most have moved up to 1.2.025 or close to that (I contract for several in the US), and the later versions will choke VS when trying to gen a schema from the DTD that XSD can process.  I had to use xmlPad (I think?), and I used XsdObjGen.exe instead of XSD.exe.  I'm currently working with Xsd2Code to get better results from that tool, both in general and specifically with CXML.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR;**
I solved this by editing the xsd file prior to converting it to c# models.

In the XSD generated from the DTD, change:

`<xs:schema xmlns="http://tempuri.org/cXML" xmlns:ds="uri:ds" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/cXML" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`

To:

`<xs:schema xmlns:ds="uri:ds" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`

**Longer explanation:**

If you use Visual studio's [XML]->[Create Schema] on the DTD file, visual studio will generate an XSD with target namespace `http://tempuri.org/cXML`.

If you generate C# models from that XSD without removing these namespace references (using xsd2code or visual studio's `xsd blah.xsd /classes`), then XmlSerializer will expect that namespace to be used in the XML you want to deserialize.

Platforms such as SAP Ariba do not use that tempuri.org namespace. The XML nodes will thus be skipped, because without the namespace reference the nodes are not recognized. I found that out because the XmlSerializer.UnknownNode event fired, telling me it doesn't recognize the nodes such as Header and Request, and it expects nodes with a tempuri.org namespace prefix.

So if you first remove the bogus namespace from the XSD, and then generate the classes (I used xsd2code for that), then you end up with valid c# (de)serializable models.

You then also don't need to use `xRoot.ElementName = "cXML";`. It will pick up the root node from the c# classes, because its not looking for a `<cXML>` tag with the tempuri.org namespace.

So this way you do not need to 'gut' the classes generated from XSD, and you can  use them as is.