# Generating cXML classes from xsd throws error "The element 'uri:ds:Signature' is missing."

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd, xsd.exe, cxml

I'm trying to generate cXML classes for version cXML 1.2.034 as per http://cxml.org/ XSD (converted by visual studio).

I converted the cXML.dtd to xsd. Then Tried running:

`xsd.exe cXML.xsd /c /language:CS /n:MyNamespace`

But it threw an error:

`Error: Error generating classes for schema 'cXML'.
  - The element 'uri:ds:Signature' is missing.`

Then I found this issue here: [Generating C# classes from XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566184/generating-c-sharp-classes-from-xsd/17278163#17278163) which seems relevant. So I downloaded **xmldsig-core-schema.xsd** from http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd

Then I ran

`xsd.exe cXML.xsd xmldsig-core-schema.xsd /c /language:CS /n:MyNamespace`

But that threw

`Error: Error generating classes for schema 'cXML_xmldsig-core-schema'.
  - The element 'uri:ds:Signature' is missing.`

I'm lost as to what "'uri:ds:Signature'" is supposed to be?

I can see that

`<xs:schema xmlns="http://tempuri.org/cXML" xmlns:ds="uri:ds" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/cXML" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`

seems wrong. I changed it to `xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"` but same issue persists.

I also tried adding reference to local signature xsd by adding

`<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>` and yes I have the file in the same directory as my own xsd file.

Comment: did you also download and convert fulfill.dtd ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I tried several attemps like you  (import the https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd schema, but did find how).

In my case, I just remove the whole line that was problematic :

```
<!-- COMMENTED <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ds:Signature" /> -->
```

and it then work perfectly.

Comment: Might work for someone. We actually ended up moving to SAP OCI which proved to be much less painful to implement.

Comment: thanks, worked fine also in 2021 (VS2019) just removing the line!